# Not able to send error caught into a response

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am making a POST request where the body is of type form-data.

The body contains the following data:

[image]

I have a middleware that is trying to parse `data`*(stringified JSON)* field in the body to JS object.

```js
/**
 * - Convert req.body.data to JSON and will attach it to body
 */
const customParser = (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    req.body = JSON.parse(req.body.data);
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: error });
  }
};

/**
 * - Route to request a community
 */
router.post(
  "/v1/user/community/request",
  userAuthorization,
  multer.single("image"),
  customParser,
  requestCommunity
);
```

The issue I am getting is when `JSON.parse()` is throwing error. I can log the error in the console but when I am sending the same error back into response I am getting an empty object.

**Response:**
[image]

**Console:**
[image]

I need help from you guys to figure out what mistake I am doing.

**Minimal, Reproducible Example:**

```js
const express = require("express");

const server = express();

const customParser = (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const testData = '{"name: "John"}';
    req.body = JSON.parse(testData);
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: error });
  }
};

server.get("/", customParser, (req, res) => {
  res.json({parsedData: req.body});
});

server.listen(3000);
```

Comment: What lib do you use as http client ? i guess the error returned by the lib contains somehting like error.response.data . try to console.log(error.response)

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @Wyck made the changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error instances can't be JSON-stringified because they don't have enumerable properties.

You can use this to return the error message in the response.

```
res.status(500).json({ error : error.message });
```

And/or `error.stack` to return the error message and the entire stack trace.